# how do sqlite android calculate this SQL correctly?

Tags: android, sqlite, select

Above i put a Example to understand my problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String sql = "SELECT \n" +
            "CAST(22955 AS REAL)*3.95";
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("db_test",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE,null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        tv.setText(c.getString(0));
        Log.i("test",c.getString(0));
    }
    c.close();
}
```

}

The result espected was `90672.25` but android return `90672.2`

Comment: What do the * mean here ?

Comment: It depends how you show it ...

Comment: sorry about this, i am trying put the number 5 with italic

Comment: @Pereira Please post the code where you are making this calculation.

Comment: just execute this query in your android and you will see that android return wrong result

Comment: @MehmoodMemon to test my code i put the query inside of app asqliteManager and run this code, the result every time is 90672.2 but i need to learn how force the result to be 90672.25

Comment: It's working for me ... please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ... *inside of app asqliteManager* so it is not a problem with your code but a bug inside this app?

Comment: See my answer. Also tell me are you displaying the result in a TextView ?

Comment: @Selvin thanks for answer. but in my app i recibe similar result

Comment: @MehmoodMemon yes i am try display in a TextView. but i put a log.i before display and i recibe same result (90672.2)

Comment: @Selvin i modify my post and put a complete code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Instead `c.getString(0)` use `"" + c.getDouble(0)`

Comment: @Selvin works your idea! i will use that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine.. I tested it in SQLite Manager and it returned 90672.25

However, if you can use [printf](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) to force it to return upto 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT printf("%.2f", CAST(22955 AS REAL)*3.95) from tablename;
```

This will always return result upto 2 decimal places.

Comment: Great. Yeah i think it's not a big deal to put it everytime. It will make sure atlease 2 decimal places are shown. You can also increase the limit.

Please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted.